# very basic basics

Tags: voltage, current, basic, load, source

I just started studying but I've been having problems because my professor assumes that we know very basic things that we actually don't.

So my questions are:

What do I need exactly to have an electric circuit? what is the minimum..I mean.

How do I know the direction of the voltage? I don't understand how some people know that by looking at the current direction.

What is a load circuit and  a source circuit?

Thanks! I know my questions might seem stupid but I need a base to understand the rest of the things..

Comment: I don't think it is a right place for "very basic basics". Read a book, really.

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/ Start with chapter 1. Your questions aren't really things you need to know, they are things you should know intuitively from what your prof tells you. Once you actually know what voltage and current are, you'll know the first answer. Once you know about voltage and current you know that a circuit is any closed loop network that allows current to flow. Source and load should be self evident. Even if it isn't to you, you can literally just google "electrical load" and have your answer.

Comment: Why don't you as your professor what he expects you to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the UK, the questions you are asking are covered by **Science** at key stage 2 and 3. You can search the web and get answers.

The BBC have a useful material, e.g.
http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/ks2/science/physical_processes/electrical_circuits/read/1/

http://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/ks3/science/energy_electricity_forces/electric_current_voltage/revision/1/